# Non-reflexive linear subspace

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

We know that if X infinite dimensional normed space, then weak topology smaller than normed topology.

This is my problem(from russian textbook of Bogachev-Smolyanov, Functional Analysis) :
Let X be non-reflexive Banach normal space.
Prove : Exist Y linear SUBSPACE of X* (dual space of X) such that Y close in norm topology X* and non-close in weak * topology X*.

Could you give me a hints to solve it?

Comment: Use the following facts: 1) a linear subspace is norm-closed if and only if it is weakly closed. 2) In a reflexive space regarded as a dual of its dual, weak and weak* topologies coincide. 3) Each closed subspace of a reflexive space is reflexive too.

Comment: But X non-reflexive Banach space.I did not understand your hint.

Comment: X non-reflexive, so embedding map i:X->X** not isomorphism, exist element F** of X** such that F is not element of X.Obviously, Ker(F**) close in normed topology X*.Is ker(F**) non-close in weak * topology X* ?